# How to compute volume of intersection of non-axis-aligned cuboids in 3D?

Tags: 3d, mathematics, volumetric

Given two cuboids in 3D space (8 vertex coordinates each) that are arbitrarily oriented, how can we find the volume of overlap between them in the fastest manner?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CGAL's [half_space_intersection_3](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_3/group__PkgConvexHull3Functions.html#gade99e8e830ff439ae242b7ab04de06c8) or [half_space_intersection_with_construction_3](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_3/group__PkgConvexHull3Functions.html#ga7517c4cbbef41338397eda273af75eb1) functions, where the half-spaces are defined by the faces of the cuboids.